# How do i make this data to use SVM for developing a model

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svm

I have the data as attached. I want to develop a model for predicting the oil rates in the upcoming 'x' years. Basically i want to develop a predictive model. Can someone please help me out with how should i transform this data to multiclass classification for using SVM model?

[This is what my data looks like. First two attributes are Date-Time and next three are my numeric attributes out of which oil rate is the one which i want to predict in the next 'x years' by developing a predictive model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x7sp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The format of your data and the problem that you are trying to solve do not translate well into a multi class classification problem. What will your classes look like? You can force fit it to ranges of the form 100-200, 200-300 etc but that is not very informative.

A regression based approach would be better suited for this as your are interested in a real valued numerical answer.

You can start off by looking at [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) and other similar models that are designed for this kind of predictive task.

Comment: I tried ARIMA, but the data is multivariate so wont ARIMA fail in that case?

Comment: There is a vector version of ARIMA called VARIMA/VARMA which handles multivariate data.

Comment: Hi, i checked that, yes its VAR. But i am not finding the implementation anywhere of VAR. I am unable to perform the task.